# Facebook Marketing API token without user input

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-marketing-api

I'm currently creating a server CLI application retrieving facebook Ads metrics through the Marketing API, it would be done as a long running service on the server doing so periodically without user input, but I can't seem to find a way to get a token for doing so.

All procedures to get an access token from facebook PHP Api seem to assume a user is there to login to facebook. I looked quickly to see if I could connect manually with curl but there is some js generated variables in the facebook login process, so that would complicate things.

Is there any way to get Marketing API insight with only an app id/secret ? Or is it possible to retrieve an access token without user input ?

The closest I've been is this :

```
Api::init(
          'appID', // App ID
          'APPSECRET',
          "appid|appstring"// APP token
        );
$campaign = new Campaign('campaignID');
$params = array(
  'date_preset' => InsightsPresets::LAST_7_DAYS,
);
$insights = $campaign->getInsights([], $params);
print_r($insights);
```

But I get an error "Cannot determine the target object for this request. Currently supported objects include ad account, business account and associated objects."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With App ID and App Secret, you can only get an App Access Token. There is no relation to any User with that one, so there is no way for Facebook to know if you are allowed to have access to the Marketing API or Insights:

> To access the Marketing API you need a user access token having the
>   permissions ads_management or ads_read

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/quickstart#access-token

**You can use and store an Extended User Token that is valid for 60 days.**

More information about Tokens and how to extend them:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Right, that's what I thought. But it doesn't solve my problem at all... Isn't there any way to get an access token without the user manually login into facebook ?

Comment: Well, I still can use an headless browser for the task, or ask clients to regenerate long liven token every two month but it's ridiculous there is no way to do it with the facebook API.

Comment: security is not ridiculous ;) - using a headless browser to login on facebook just to avoid authorizing sounds...weird. and is most likely not allowed. what´s the problem with authorizing the user in a proper way?

Comment: I don't really see how that's a security feature. I gather stats from Google Analytics and Adword APIs, and it's possible to get tokens with a private key stored on the server with their API.

Comment: it works the same way with the graph api. you can´t get access to google analytics or the adwords api without a user login either.

Comment: look at the bold text in my answer, that´s what you can use. the links about tokens in my answer tell you how to get an extended user token.

Comment: I assure you it's possible with google APIs ! But yeah, I don't think I will find any better answer. Yours is accepted.

Comment: i know how the google APIs work, i have used them on a regular basis ;) - you do need to authorize an account and store a token, it´s pretty much the same. either way, the extended user token is what you would want to use/store.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have access to [Business Manager](https://business.facebook.com)? You can generate a System User there which comes with a non-expiring token. [See here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/businessmanager/systemuser/v2.5).

Comment: Could you please explain ***how to** generate a System User there which comes with a non-expiring token* ? Or, please include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. This answer can become invalid if the linked page changes.